# If value in both table then assign 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case-when

```
    Table1  CompanyID  Location  #-of-employees
          5234       NY          10
          5268       DC          2
          5879       NY          8
          6897       KS          100
          8789       CA          1
          9992       OH          201
          9877       TX          15

Table2 CompanyID   #-of-Shareholders
          5234            5
          5879            2
          6897            4
          8789            2
```

I have two table with the column CompanyID. In table2 you can find companies that have shareholders and in table1 you can find all the companies. So in table 1 I want to add a dummy variable that assign a 1 if the companyID is in table2(which means the company has shareholders) and a 0 if not.

```
Expected output:
    Table1  CompanyID  Location  #-of-employees Dummy
              5234       NY          10           1
              5268       DC          2            0
              5879       NY          8            1
              6897       KS          100          1
              8789       CA          1            1
              9992       OH          201          0
              9877       TX          15           0
```

I tried using this query but it doesn't give me the output I expect.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN companyID IN table2 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS dummy
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Subquery for this. the below code working fine.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN companyID in(select CompanyId  from table2) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS dummy
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T1.CompanyID = T2.CompanyID) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS Dummy
FROM    Table1 AS T1;
```

Answer (score 0):

*If your DB's version is `2012+` then, use with `left join` as :*

```
select t1.*, iif(#_of_Shareholders is null, 0, 1) as dummy
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2
    on ( t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID );
```

*else*

```
select t1.*, 
       ( case when #_of_Shareholders is null then 0 else  1 end ) 
       as dummy
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2
    on ( t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID );
```

*or*

```
select t1.*,
       sign(coalesce(#_of_Shareholders,0))
       as dummy
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2
    on ( t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID );
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/IOI63591)